# How to iterate over Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStore elements?

Tags: rally

I tried using something as follows, however it is not working:

```
store.each(function(record){
    console.log("record+++++", record);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

TreeStore has a slightly different interface than a regular store, which is annoying.  I usually do something like this:

```
_.each(store.getRootNode().childNodes, function(record) {
    console.log(record);
});
```

Comment: store.getRootNode().children returns null..... :(......any suggestions?